# Powershell script

Tags: powershell, attachments

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script that would email, as attachments, all files in each subfolder of C:\Reports\ together in an email. For instance, if the subfolders are C:\Reports\ABC having a.txt, b.xml and c.jpg and C:\Reports\DEF having d.txt, e.xml and f.pdf, the code should email a.txt, b.xml and c.jpg in one email and d.txt, e.xml and f.pdf in another.
I wrote the below code:-

```
$Directory=Get-ChildItem "C:\Reports\" -Directory 
$Cred = Get-Credential 
Foreach($d in $Directory) { 
Write-Host "Working on directory $($d.FullName)..." 
$files=Get-ChildItem -Path "$($d.FullName)"
cd $d.Fullname  
Send-MailMessage -From "vallabhherlekar@gmail.com" -To "vallabhherlekar@gmail.com" -Subject "test" -SmtpServer "smtp.gmail.com" -Port "587" -Attachments $files -BodyAsHtml "test msg" -Credential $Cred -UseSsl
}
```

However this seems to attaching only the last file in each subfolder, then moving on to the next folder and email. I wonder how Get-ChildItem - File can be properly used with Send-MailMessage - Attachments to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some (untested) code:

```
#Connection Details
$username="john"
$password="password"
$smtpServer = "mail.server.local"
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage

#Change port number for SSL to 587
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25) 

#Uncomment Next line for SSL  
#$smtp.EnableSsl = $true

$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $username, $password )

#From Address
$msg.From = "john@gmail.com"
#To Address, Copy the below line for multiple recipients
$msg.To.Add("test@gmail.com")

#Message Body
$msg.Body="Please See Attached Files"

#Message Subject
$msg.Subject = "Email with Multiple Attachments"

#your file location
$files=Get-ChildItem "C:\Reports\"

Foreach($file in $files)
{
Write-Host "Attaching File :- " $file
$attachment = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment -ArgumentList $file.FullName
$msg.Attachments.Add($attachment)
}

$smtp.Send($msg)
$attachment.Dispose();
$msg.Dispose();
```

[source](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/2038-powershell-email-all-files-in-folder)

Comment: My Bad. My code works. I had some files having size 0 bytes. Only those weren't getting sent. Another thing I want to do is that once the sub-directory's contents have been emailed I need to delete it and all the files it contains within the loop. Would someone be able to help me with that?

Comment: That's another question, but just add another `Foreach($file in $files)` loop to do that.